# Plot tree-like data vs time (including 1-child nodes)

Tags: r, ggplot2, recursion, tree

I have some simple tree-like edge-data (e.g. data below) with the following characteristics:

- there is a root node (`0`)
- all non-root nodes have exactly one parent, but 0-to-many children (including 1)
- there is a time `t` associated with each edge (or equivalently each unique node in `i.fr`)
- we can compute `dt` as below, if helpful

I want to plot these data as a tree, with time along one dimension, so that edge lengths are proportional to `dt` (e.g. sketch below). **How can I do this in R?**

I explored `ape` and `data.tree` packages, and `ggtree`, but none seem to provide interface for creating tree objects from edge lists, and I think my data (with 1-child nodes) are rejected as some types of trees?

#### Sample Data

```
tree = data.frame(
   t = c( 0, 1, 1, 4, 5, 7),
i.fr = c( 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5),
i.to = c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  dt = c(NA, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2))
```

#### Fake `phylo`

```
fake.phylo = list(
  edge = cbind(tree$i.fr,tree$i.to),
  tip.label = c('4','6'),
  Nnode = 5,
  edge.length = tree$dt)
class(fake.phylo) = 'phylo'
phylo.tree = as.phylo(fake.phylo) # works 
plot(tree) # (!) tree badly conformed; cannot plot. Check the edge matrix.
```

#### Desired Result

[image: tree]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzWNBmjyv7Y), a reasonably full-featured solution is:

```
library('ggplot2')

.tip.pos <<- 0
.recurse.tree = function(ii,par=0,gen=0){
  # recursively walk the tree and extract the following rows:
  # index (ordered by tree search), generation, position, n direct children, n total children
  b.par = ii[,1]==par
  i.chi = ii[b.par,2]
  n.chi = length(i.chi)
  if (n.chi > 0){
    mat.chi = matrix(nrow=5,unlist(lapply(i.chi,function(i){
      .recurse.tree(ii=ii[!b.par,,drop=FALSE],par=i,gen=gen+1)
    })))
    par.pos = mean(range(mat.chi[3,mat.chi[1,] %in% i.chi])) # midpoint of direct children
    mat.par.chi = matrix(nrow=5,c(par,gen,par.pos,n.chi,ncol(mat.chi),mat.chi))
  } else {
    .tip.pos <<- .tip.pos + 1
    mat.par = matrix(nrow=5,c(par,gen,.tip.pos,0,0))
  }
}

plot.tree = function(tree,...){
  # plot a transmission tree vs time
  tree.data = .recurse.tree(as.matrix(tree[c('par','chi')]))
  tree = rbind(c(-1,-1,0,NA),tree)            # append dummy root
  tree = tree[match(tree.data[1,],tree$chi),] # reorder to match tree.data
  tree$gen = factor(tree.data[2,])            # generation
  tree$pos = tree.data[3,]                    # position
  tree$child.direct = tree.data[4,]           # n direct children
  tree$child.total = tree.data[5,]            # n total children
  pc.map = match(tree$par,tree$chi)           # lookup index for chi -> par
  tree$pos.par = tree$pos[pc.map]             # parent position
  tree$t.par = tree$t[pc.map]                 # parent t
  g = ggplot(tree) +
    geom_segment(aes_string(y='t.par',x='pos.par',xend='pos',yend='t'),alpha=.5) +
    geom_point(aes_string(x='pos',y='t',...)) +
    scale_x_continuous(labels=NULL,breaks=NULL) + labs(x='')
}

tree = data.frame(
   t = c( 0, 1, 1, 4, 5, 7),
 par = c( 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5),
 chi = c( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  dt = c(NA, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2))
g = plot.tree(tree,color='gen')
ggsave('Rplots.png',w=4,h=4)
```

#### Result

[image: mwe result]

#### Extending

The code above can be easily modified to give some nice results, e.g. with bigger data, custom aes, and [ggMarginal](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggExtra/versions/0.10.0/topics/ggMarginal):

[image: fancy result]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `ggraph`; I have no idea how well this generalises for trees with more than one split.

```r
library(ggraph)
tree %>%
    select(i.fr, i.to) %>%
    graph_from_data_frame(directed = TRUE) %>%
    ggraph() +
    geom_node_point() +
    geom_edge_link(arrow = arrow(length = unit(4, 'mm')), end_cap = circle(3, 'mm')) +
    geom_node_label(aes(label = name)) + 
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_y_continuous(
        limits = c(0, max(tree$dt, na.rm = TRUE)), 
        breaks = c(0:(max(tree$dt, na.rm = TRUE))), 
        labels = rev(c(0:(max(tree$dt, na.rm = TRUE)))),
        minor_breaks = NULL, 
        position = "left") +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.1, 0.1), breaks = NULL) +
    labs(x = "", y = "Time")
```

[image]

You can also force `coord_fixed()` which gives you a narrower version

```r
# ... Same as before +
coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but something is off in with time -- e.g. node "4" should be at t=4, not t=3. I think this plots the generations. I have a solution, will post in a moment.